# Fill inner cells based on margins

Tags: r, matrix, rounding

I have the following data

```
margin1 <- c(72,34,446,40,33,71,2,96)
margin2 <- c(70,36,455,41,36,56,2,98)

propabilities <- matrix(1/8,8,8)
```

Now I would like to fill the inner cells of a 8x8 matrix by multiplying the following logic

```
matrix <- matrix(0,8,8)
matrix[1,] <- probabilities[1,]*margin2[1]
matrix[2,] <- probabilities[2,]*margin2[2]
matrix[3,] <- probabilities[3,]*margin2[3]
matrix[4,] <- probabilities[4,]*margin2[4]
matrix[5,] <- probabilities[5,]*margin2[5]
matrix[6,] <- probabilities[6,]*margin2[6]
matrix[7,] <- probabilities[7,]*margin2[7]
matrix[8,] <- probabilities[8,]*margin2[8]
```

However, what makes this difficult is, that the inner cells should always be integers. Therefore, I wrote the following rounding function:

```
rounding <- function(x) {

    output <- matrix(0,8,8)
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
      obj <- x[i,]
      y <- floor(obj)
      indices <- tail(order(obj-y), round(sum(obj)) - sum(y))
      y[indices] <- y[indices] + 1
      output[i,]<-  y
      }
    x <- output

  return(x)
}
```

My expected output is the following:

```
matrix <- rounding(matrix)
```

While this works to ensure, that the rowSums of the matrix object are equal to margin2, the colSums do not equal margin1. This however, is exactly what I would need. Is there any way to rewrite the rounding function, that would achieve this?

Comment: what is `marginal2`? You don't define it anywhere. Is it the same as `margin2`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It was meant to be margin2 and margin1, which I introduced in the beginning.

Comment: Is it possible that you just need `propabilities*margin2`?

Comment: F.Y.I, there is already a `round` function in base R so please rename your function to something else

Comment: @RonakShah I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Sotos You were right, it should have been margin2 and I have also renamed the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided I have understood you correctly, the problem you're describing refers to the question, how to fill a matrix given its row and column sums (the "margins" as you call them).

In your particular case, you're trying to fill an 8x8 matrix. Since you have 64 unknowns, but 8 + 8 - 1 = 15 independent equations (8 row sums, 8 column sums, minus 1 because the *sum* of the row sums must be equal to the sum of the column sums)  the bottom line is that there *doesn't exist a unique solution*, and instead there will be many.

If matrix values can be *rational numbers* you can fill the matrix with values `margin2_i * margin1_j / sum(margin2)` for row `i` and column `j`, or in R

```
mat <- margin2 %*% t(margin1) / sum(margin1)
mat
#    [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]        [,5]       [,6]
#[1,]  6.3476071  2.99748111  39.319899  3.5264484  2.90931990  6.2594458
#[2,]  3.2644836  1.54156171  20.221662  1.8136020  1.49622166  3.2191436
#[3,] 41.2594458 19.48362720 255.579345 22.9219144 18.91057935 40.6863980
#[4,]  3.7178841  1.75566751  23.030227  2.0654912  1.70403023  3.6662469
#[5,]  3.2644836  1.54156171  20.221662  1.8136020  1.49622166  3.2191436
#[6,]  5.0780856  2.39798489  31.455919  2.8211587  2.32745592  5.0075567
#[7,]  0.1813602  0.08564232   1.123426  0.1007557  0.08312343  0.1788413
#[8,]  8.8866499  4.19647355  55.047859  4.9370277  4.07304786  8.7632242
# [,7]       [,8]
#[1,] 0.176322418  8.4634761
#[2,] 0.090680101  4.3526448
#[3,] 1.146095718 55.0125945
#[4,] 0.103274559  4.9571788
#[5,] 0.090680101  4.3526448
#[6,] 0.141057935  6.7707809
#[7,] 0.005037783  0.2418136
#[8,] 0.246851385 11.8488665
```

We can confirm that indeed

1. the row sum of `mat` is equal to `margin2`

   ```
   identical(rowSums(mat), margin2)
   #[1] TRUE
   ```

   and that
2. the column sum of `mat` is equal to `margin1`

   ```
   identical(colSums(mat), margin1)
   #[1] TRUE
   ```

The problem is more complex if you want to restrict matrix values to only *integer values*. Here I would refer you to an [excellent post on Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1969567/525967) that illustrates an iterative solution strategy.

Comment: Thank you! That post on Mathematics was really helpful!